# SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql, mysql

I think this is a pretty basic question and I have looked around on the site but I am not sure what to search on to find the answer.

I have an SQL table that looks like:

```
studentId  period  class  
1          1       math  
1          2       english  
2          1       math  
2          2       history
```

I am looking for a SELECT statement that finds the studentId that is taking math 1st period and english 2nd period.  I have tried something like `SELECT studentID WHERE ( period = 1 AND class= "math" ) AND ( period = 2 AND class = "english" )` but that has not worked.

I have also thought about changing my table to be:

```
studentId  period1  period2  period3  period4  period5 etc
```

But I think I want to be adding things besides classes like after school activities and wanted to be able to expand easily without constantly having to add columns.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subqueries to do each individually and get only results where both subqueries match.

```
Select StudentId FROM table WHERE 
    StudentId IN 
       (SELECT studentID FROM table WHERE ( period = 1 AND class= "math" ) ) 
AND 
    StudentId IN 
       (SELECT studentID FROM table WHERE ( period = 2 AND class= "english" ) )
```

**Edit - added**

I have not tested this myself, but I was curious about performance considerations, so I looked it up.    I found this quote:

> Many Transact-SQL statements that
>   include subqueries can be
>   alternatively formulated as joins.
>   Other questions can be posed only with
>   subqueries. In Transact-SQL, there is
>   usually no performance difference
>   between a statement that includes a
>   subquery and a semantically equivalent
>   version that does not. However, in
>   some cases where existence must be
>   checked, a join yields better
>   performance. Otherwise, the nested
>   query must be processed for each
>   result of the outer query to ensure
>   elimination of duplicates. In such
>   cases, a join approach would yield
>   better results. The following is an
>   example showing both a subquery SELECT
>   and a join SELECT that return the same
>   result set:

here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575.aspx

Comment: true but kinda overkill, isnt it? :D but +1 for contributing a correct subquery example

Comment: It's not necessary to have two subqueries, though - one can be merged in the top-level query.

Comment: @Joe Hopfgartner: what he wants is INTERSECT, and David's approach is the canonical formulation of intersect.

Comment: true @margin but i like this answer because it demonstrates a different approach very clear and subqueries would be in practice not be the weapon of choice anyway! but it is important to understand different possibilities and therefore its good to put them as simple as possible.

Comment: @Joe Hopfgartner, It may be overkill and if performance becomes an issue, it shouldn't be used, but for code clarity I thought it was pretty good. Your answer was pretty good too, but personally I would have to think about it if I were a maintenance programmer and I needed to adjust it.  However, I did vote you up because it would definitely work.

Comment: Thanks this has worked, although I'm curious how this scales on a performance standpoint.  Say I have 8 periods and 10 after-school activities someone can search on.  Would having 18 of these subqueries be efficient enough or do I need to change my table format?

Comment: well the count/having solution will perform better as its only one query. no joins, no subquieries at all

Answer (score 3):

try something like:

```
select studentid from table where ( period = 1 AND class= "math" ) or ( period = 2 AND class = 
"english" ) group by studentid having count(*) >= 2
```

the idea is to select all who meet the first criteria or the second criteria, group it by person and see where all are met by checking the number of rows grouped

Answer (score 2):

You could also do a self join

```
SELECT  t1.studentID  
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t1.studentID = t2.studentID   
WHERE ( t1.period = 1 AND t1.class= "math" )    
  AND ( t2.period = 2 AND t2.class = "english" )
```

Comment: +1.  After finding that article I was about to include this as a second possibility in my answer, but you beat me to it.  Nice!